# display json table data with new line

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, html-table

**Expected Output**
[image]

I am facing an issue in javascript, I want to do display table data `success`, `fail`, `Time` column  with new lines.

What should i do? Anyone help me?

my code is here:

```js
        var responseList = [{
            "summary": {
                "id": 898,
                "name": "Ben",
                "number": "399468789",
                "status": "fail",
                "success": "2",
                "fail": "1",
                "created_at": "2020-07-10 14:02:13",
            },
        }];


        var table = document.querySelector('#my-table');
        var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
        table.appendChild(tbody);


        for (var i = 0; i < responseList.length; i++) {

            var tr = tbody.insertRow();

            var summary = responseList[i]["summary"];
            console.log(summary);
            for (var key in summary) {
                if (summary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    console.log(key + " -> " + summary[key]);
                    var td = tr.insertCell();
                    td.innerHTML = summary[key];                    
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>

</head>

<body>
    <table id="my-table" border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Mobile Number</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Success</th>
                <th>Failed</th>
                <th>Time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>


    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please show expected results for more than one item. Not really clear what layout is expected as it can be interpreted several ways only showing one

Comment: i updated the attached expected result photo [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl)

Comment: Why not just use two tables and add a row to each as you loop over the array?